# CSS Image Position Stack

Tags: css, position

I have group of image and I want to display it as list (li), but I don't want the bullet show up, plus I want to create it horizontally. Does anyone know what CSS should I make? I'm trying to create it with my CSS, but it displayed only 1 image.. It looks like my image got stacking.

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you even try looking up what properties of a list can be changed using CSS? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this with CSS.

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none; /* hide default list-item bullets */
}
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    /* OR */
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. But there's an white space between image, how to remove that?

Comment: You should experiment with the margin/padding on the ul and li's.